# XLA-able dynamic slicing

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

Is there any way to dynamically slice a tensor according to a random number generator in an XLA-compiled function?  For example:

```py
@tf.function(experimental_compile=True)
def random_slice(input, max_slice_size):
    offset = tf.squeeze(tf.random.uniform([1], minval=0, maxval=input.shape[0]-max_slice_size, dtype=tf.int32))
    sz = tf.squeeze(tf.random.uniform([1], minval=1, maxval=max_slice_size, dtype=tf.int32))

    indices = tf.range(offset, offset+sz)  # Non-XLA-able due to non-static bounds

    return tf.gather(input, indices)

x = tf.ones([50, 50])
y = random_slice(x, 4)
```

This code fails to compile because XLA requires that the arguments to `tf.range` are known at compile time.  Is there a recommended workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The underlying issue here is that XLA needs to know, statically, the shapes of all `Tensor`s in the program. In this case it complains about `tf.range` because its output is not knowable given the random inputs. You might instead be able to get away with generating a masked version (zeroing out the elements you don't need, using something like tensor_scatter_nd_update) and using that masked version downstream (hard to say exactly how, without seeing more context on how `y` is to be used).